# Can't run npm commands behind a proxy

Tags: windows, unix, npm, proxy

I'm using npm behind a proxy which doesn't requires username and password, I've tried all different commands but without any result, the internet connection is working fine on command line , here's is the command I've used :

```
-  npm config set proxy http://10.23.201.11:3128
-  npm config set https-proxy http://10.23.201.11:3128
-  npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
-  npm config set strict-ssl false
-  npm config set bin-links false
```

** These are the errors I'm getting when trying to run an npm command :
example :   npm install -g react-native-cli

```
   - npm rollback failed
   - npm ERR! code E502
   - 502 Bad Gateway: react-native-cli@latest
```